# Sending RAW data to IP (TCP/IP)

Tags: sockets, tcp, c++-cli, winsock

I'm trying to learn some WinSock and stuck in place. I want to sent RAW packet (256 bytes) to another device in the network. This device is just a listener. I'm using VC++ 2010 and WinSock.

**So there a code I'm working on:**

```
// winsock.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <WinSock2.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

WORD RequiredVersion;
    WSADATA WData;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    long val;
    struct hostent *he;
    char host[128];
    int port;

    printf("HOST: ");
    scanf("%s",host);
    printf("PORT: ");
    scanf("%d",&port);
    printf("Data to send: ");
    scanf("%d",&val);

    RequiredVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 0);

    if (WSAStartup(RequiredVersion, &WData) != 0) {
    printf("ERROR! WinSock2\n");
    return 1;
    }


    //he = gethostbyaddr((char *) host, 4, AF_INET);
    he = gethostbyname(host);
    if (he == NULL) {
    printf("host not found.\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*) he->h_addr);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
            //SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP); 

    connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    printf("SENDING %d TO %s\n",val,inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
    val = htonl(val);



    send(s, (char*) &val, sizeof(long), 0);
    printf("WAITING FOR RESPONSE...\n");
    recv(s, (char*) &val, sizeof(long), 0);
    val = ntohl(val);
    printf("RE: %d\n", val);
    closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

**The problems I've got:**

1. I'm probably not creating a real RAW socket.
2. I think I should not use 'gethostbyname', but I don't know how to replace it for an const. IP
3. My program doesn't sent any data over LAN. I'm using WireShark to check this. I think this can be a problem with 'gethostbyname'

Any tips? I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Please stick to one question. This question is formulated as a code review with no less than THREE questions attached. I think you should start by making a minimal question for asking how to use a hardcoded IP instead of using `gethostbyname`. Once this confusion is out of the way, it will be easier for everybody to understand any problems in the code.

Comment: You seem to be using [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI). Is this intentional? You might be able to attract more people here if you convert your project to standard C++.

Comment: See if this helps: [SOCK_RAW Demystified](http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw), [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx). Re: `gethostbyname` and IP address - you might be looking for `inet_addr`.

Comment: Okay, just changed code to const. IP. Like this: `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.130");` But data is still not sent.

Comment: You should also update this question. There is an "edit"-link. The code you include in the question should be a [Short, Self Contained and Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem you are having. You should also remove your list of three questions and clearly state your *one* remaining question. Maybe your question is "I think this should send data, but when I monitor with WireShark, nothing is sent. If I change the socket type to `SOCK_DGRAM` it seems to work. Why will it not work with `SOCK_RAW`?" As it stands you are not asking a clear question.

Comment: @bluemuz: You don't need to use `SOCK_RAW` unless you need full control over the IP header itself.  In 99.9999999999% of cases, you only need to use `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP) or `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP) instead.  Given the code you have shown, I am guessing that `SOCK_STREAM` is what you are looking for.